# Turn Off All Emacs Formatting

Tags: emacs

How do you turn off all of Emacs' built in formatting? I simply want it to indent 4 spaces when I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and not have Emacs try and determine how far to indent.  I don't want various colors based upon what file type I'm editing.  I just want it to operate the the most basic way, like a text edit program on a PC/MAC.  Is there a way to simply turn off all auto formatting, auto indenting, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is simply [text-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Mode.html):

```
M-x text-mode
```

And as you noticed, to disable the automated indent:

```
M-x paragraph-indent-text-mode
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried that, however I run into the problem where it still indents to the furthest indention point in a block of code.  I don't even want it to interpret that, I'd just like it to indent 1 tab width, not seek out the current indention level.

Comment: Actually it looks like, from that link you provided, that what I'm looking for is: paragraph-indent-text-mode.  How do I set that to be on at all times in my .emacs file?

Comment: Yes you're wright! I'm going to edit my post to add this new piece of information.

Comment: Any idea how to add that to the .emacs file so it's always loaded when I open a file?

Comment: @xKevinx Sorry, I tried several things, but none of them worked :/

Comment: (deleting and reposting comments, due to a bad typo): Trying to override the major mode uniformly for all types of files and buffers is not an appropriate thing to do in Emacs; but if you have a specific set of file types that you wish to edit in this way, it's easy to configure that. e.g.: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt\\'" . paragraph-indent-text-mode))` will affect all `.txt` files. You could extend that regexp to apply to a list of extensions like so: `"\\.\\(txt\\|foo\\|bar\\|baz\\)\\'"`.

Comment: Also, if you genuinely want *no* major mode behaviours, you can use `fundamental-mode`. It's not the intended way of using Emacs, of course; but you can do it if you really want to.

Comment: This is what I've added to my .emacs file and it seems to be working: (setq default-major-mode 'paragraph-indent-text-mode)